# PHPWord Template Processor Clone Row and Set Values table problem

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

So i have a table in a docx and inside one of the row of the table, i want to fill it with an array data
template in docx

```
${title} : ${content}
```

expected value

```
test  : 1  
test2 : 2
```

my code to enter the data is down below

```
 $dataRowTitle = "title";  
 $dataRow = [["title" => "test", "content" => "1"  ], ["title" => "test2", "content" => "2"  ]]  
 $templateProcessor->cloneRowAndSetValues($dataRowTitle, $dataRow);
```

but what happen is instead doing as expected result, it makes a new table row that filled with the first index of dataRow array. if my dataRow array have 3 index than it will make 3 new row.
Anything that i can do to make it write the next index just below the first data and not making a new table row?

Answer (score 0):

`cloneRowAndSetValues()` method is used to ***create as many new rows as there are items in your array***.

The steps to show all the data in *a single row:*

- Make an array of all titles (with `array_map()`)
- Make an array of all contents (with `array_map()`)
- join all titles with newline (`\n`) and use `setValue()` method to write
- join all contents with newline (`\n`) and use `setValue()` method to write

Here is an example code:

```
$dataRows = [
    ["title" => "test", "content" => "1"],
    ["title" => "test2", "content" => "2"]
];

// array of titles
$allTitles = array_map(function($data){return $data['title'];}, $dataRows);

// array of content
$allContent = array_map(function($data){return $data['content'];}, $dataRows);

$templateProcessor->setValue('title', implode("\n", $allTitles));
$templateProcessor->setValue('content', implode("\n", $allContent));
```

Try `\r\n` if `\n` does not work.